# show running ms-access databases from process in c#

Tags: c#, ms-access, process

In c#, Is there a way to know which ms-access database is running by searching in the running processes ?
if not, is there another way to see to full name of the running MS-Access databases ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

As long as you know the process ID or Name, you're golden. You can use something like this to collect process information:

```
Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();

 foreach(Process theprocess in processlist){
 Console.WriteLine(“Process: {0} ID: {1}”, theprocess.ProcessName, theprocess.Id);
}
```

Then you can basically filter on the name. You find the Process object in the System.Diagnostics namespace.

Hope that fixes it for ya :)

Comment: ProcessName will give me: "msaccess", not the name of the DB file

Comment: You can dig deeper. Process contains a property named StartInfo that should give you the command line parameters passed to the process upon start.

Comment: Disregard my previous comment, that only applies to processes that you started yourself. For retrieving processes that were started outside of your running program, you'll need to dip your toes into WMI. Some discussion on this is here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8efe163b-927e-4895-9983-b8c47b515d7c/how-to-get-the-command-line-parameters-from-a-different-process-in-c?forum=netfxbcl

Comment: WMI will return "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15\root\office15\MSACCESS.EXE"